# Security review test org for managed package

Tags: managed-package, security-review

According to [Security Review Test Info](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_Test_Info),

"Starting March 1, 2017 full Locker Compliance will be mandatory to submit for the security review. Therefore, the Developer Edition test environment provided for the security review must have Locker Service enabled. Enterprise edition and sandbox orgs will not be acceptable test environments starting March 1, 2017 "

We generally test on a "enterprise" or "partner enterprise" org created through environment hub. Will this environment not be acceptable for security review?

Do we need to create a free developer org for security review?

Comment: You can use the ISV Developer Org, it doesn't have to literally be the free 10MB Developer Org, if you have access to the Partner Portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a developer org from your environment hub .Make sure when you create developer edition or partner developer edition is selected .

Also make sure in critical updates ,LockerService is turned on and your lightning components work inside the locker .

Comment: Thanks for your comment. From the blog, I understood that they require free developer edition orgs with packages installed. But if you need more users for testing purposes, one would have to go for partner developer editions through envrionment hub.  Is there any particular reason for testing on developer orgs (created through enviornment hub) vs enterprise editions?

Comment: Developer orgs have more features than either enterprise editions .Apart from that I do not have further insights on why developer edition